# Like Box from url with punycode?

Tags: facebook-social-plugins, facebook-likebox, punycode

I´m trying to make a Like Box from this url:http://www.facebook.com/pages/I-karriären/238394972905409?sk=wall
I try generate the code from facebook developer page:http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/
but only get this message "Could not retrieve id for the specified page. Please verify correct href was passed in."
I also tried the url in punycode format; http://www.facebook.com/pages/xn--I-karriren-w5a/238394972905409?sk=wall
but still get the same message. What could be wrong? It is not a personal page.

Answer (score 0):

You should avoid adding any parameters to the URL of Facebook Page to use it with [Like Box](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) social plugin, this will work:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/I-karriären/238394972905409
```

But next one will not, since it's pointing to wall part of page:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/I-karriären/238394972905409?sk=wall
```

BTW, punycode part is actually wouldn't change anything since Page Name in the URL have a display only matter (this may be changed in future), next URL will work in the same way as the first one or punycode version:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/238394972905409
```